# Possible StartWith(x) with multiple value?

Tags: c#, string

I tried to do a searchbox to filter a multiple value by using the `StartsWith`. Is this possible the `StartsWith` to add-in the multiple value besides the "X", like added in the "Y", "z"? If yes, how to add-in?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

string dateStart = txtDateStart.Text;
string dateEnd = txtDateEnd.Text;

string filter = txtFilter.Text;
if (!filter.StartsWith("X")) return;
```

Comment: Not with a single call, no. But you can call `StartsWith` multiple times: `if (!filter.StartsWith("X") && !filter.StartsWith("Y"))` for example. Or you could investigate using a regular expression.

Comment: Please be careful when selecting tags. Don't just write a single letter and then press `Enter` without looking to make sure the correct tag was selected (like in this case, it likely isn't correct).

Comment: How is this related to MySQL? In any case, you can use regular expressions if you want to match multiple values, eg `Regex.IsMatch(filter,"^(potato|banana).*")` or `^[XYZ].*`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, sorry. I have removed from SQL community.

Answer (score 1):

You can just implement `StartsWithAny`; let it be extension method:

```
using System.Linq;

...

public static class MyStringExtensions {
  public bool StartsWithAny(this string value, params string[] prefixes) { 
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || prefixes is null)
      return false;

    return prefixes.Any(prefix => value.StartsWith(prefix)); 
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
string myString = "Lorem ipsum";

if (myString.StartsWithAny("X", "Y", "z")) {
  ...
}
``
```

Answer (score 0):

No. `StartsWith()` works only with single value.

For multiple values you can use Regex, for example, or collections of `{"X", "Y", "z"}` with comparisons

```
        String[] arr = new String[] { "X", "Y", "z"};
        string filter = "Y or XYZ test string";
        foreach(string f in arr) 
            if (filter.StartsWith(f)) {
                Console.WriteLine("Starts with {0}", f);
                break; 
            }
```

or shorter

```
Console.WriteLine(arr.FirstOrDefault(x => filter.StartsWith(x)));
```

Comment: What if I want to show all value result on my list when I key nothing on my search box?